# Installation of Virtual Box on Mac OS -- Kernel Driver Not loaded

Tags: macos, virtualbox

While trying to install Virtual Box on Mac OS the installation fails and show me the failure message. But still I get a copy of Virtual Box installed. When add a KMDV file and try to start it I get an error saying Kernel driver not installed. I am attaching those messages here.
Does others also face similar issue, would be nice to get some views on this.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to Security and Privacy / General in your System Settings. You will see that software from Oracle has been blocked. Allow it, and the software will work. The 'allow Oracle' option only exists for 30mins after the installer error.

See Apple's [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html) on this.

Comment: FYI, the option to allow Oracle only lasts for 30mins after the installer error message. See [this Virtual Box forum thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=84778#p402556) and [this Apple technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html)

Comment: i have the same Problem but there is nothing to allow in my system settings.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked in my case:  https://superuser.com/questions/1436347/cant-allow-virtualbox-installation-in-security-privacy-under-macos

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I don't get the Allow button.

Comment: I'm using macOS Big Sur, I followed the above process but it was not working for me as well. After updating the Big Sur latest version it was working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've upgraded to MacOS (Catalina) 10.15.1 and I've upgraded to VB 6.0.14 and started getting above issue while starting my earlier guestOs i.e. Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

I've tried various solution, but nothing worked except this:

```sh
spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963
```

So you need to run this command in recovery mode terminal **ONLY** (*Top Menu Bar* » *Utilities* » *Terminal*). I was avoiding going into recovery mode but when nothing worked and you don't have any other option; you can save this command and note it down in some mobile app or notepad.

P.S.: In order to open recovery mode, you need to restart your system and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Mac OS (Catalina) **10.15.4** and Virtual box **6.1.8**. I was facing the same issue since past couple of days and nothing seems working for me, not even the command the guy mentioned above. Finally, I have downgraded my Virtual box version to **6.1.6** and installed the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack for VB 6.1.6. Now everything is working fine.

Download link: https://licensing.psu.ac.th/virtualbox-released/

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above failed (as was my case), try follow the procedure described here: https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2373#issuecomment-676121212, that is:

1. Boot in Recovery mode (command + r)
2. Open the terminal and type: `chflags restricted /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/private/var/db/KernelExtensionManagement`
3. Reboot and install VirtualBox

Answer (score -1):

If you can not see the "allow oracle",
run this in terminal

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

then the option, (o) Anywhere , will come out.